# How to show clip content of the background image and only show border?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

This codepen https://codepen.io/Chester/pen/QPoyjN here shows how to do border animation. It works well, however they are using `white` background and I want to make background of the box dynamic.

```
<div class="rainbow">
    Rainbow border
</div>
```

Suppose the div already has some class which sets it's background. How do I make the `::after` background use already existing background?

Is there any solution to clip background from content and only show `::before` background to borders?

Here's the magic scss code:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}

.rainbow {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2rem;
    
    &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -2;
        left: -50%;
        top: -50%;
        width: 200%;
        height: 200%;
        background-color: #399953;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
        background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
        background-image: linear-gradient(#399953, #399953), linear-gradient(#fbb300, #fbb300), linear-gradient(#d53e33, #d53e33), linear-gradient(#377af5, #377af5);
        animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
    }
    
    &::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        left: 6px;
        top: 6px;
        width: calc(100% - 12px);
        height: calc(100% - 12px);
        background: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background: inherit;`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}
.rainbow {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: pink;
}
.rainbow::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  left: -50%;
  top: -50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: #399953;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 50%;
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#399953, #399953), linear-gradient(#fbb300, #fbb300), linear-gradient(#d53e33, #d53e33), linear-gradient(#377af5, #377af5);
  -webkit-animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
          animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}
.rainbow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 12px);
  height: calc(100% - 12px);
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rainbow">
    Rainbow border
</div>
```

Comment: okay this works but what if background color has opacity or alpha channel? then the background of spinner is visible?

see here https://codepen.io/rudevdr/pen/NWaQKMr